# talend :: not able to connect 2 tMap output

Tags: talend

my doubt is how to connect 2 tMap output into a single tMap.I have done the below sample job to execute a stored procedure based on result of a query and now i want to join the stored procedure output and query output.

[image: talend vesion DI 5.6.3 sample job]

Comment: are you passing any input from query output tmap_1 to storedprocedure..?

Comment: query output is not directly send to sp but after some processing and based on condition it send to sp.

Comment: one option is that you can write output of both SP and tMap_1 into two files and then later read these and join post your step of tmap_1..

Comment: Good option !!! but the data I am dealing with is very difficult to store into a file and retrieve as it is encrypted data and can contain anything, even the delimiters also.can  suggest any other option @garpitmzn

Comment: if volume is not a concern then you can use thashoutput/thashinput components to keep it in memory

Comment: Volume is also a concern b/c each of the row will contain XML of size 131072 byte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, just added new parameter on the same map as a backup param instead of putting additional Map and processing and join. Here is the screenshot

[image]

Simple and easy solution :)